# Schedule reminders broken in 4.6.8

Tags: api

using civi 4.6.8

needed a notification sent to a volunteer when they sign up for an event.  setup a scheduled reminder to catch the action.  everything work ok and email was added to the queue in civicrm_action_schedule.

forced the job to execute.

got back

Finished execution of Send Scheduled Reminders with result: Failure, Error message: API (ActionLog, get) does not exist (join the API team and implement it!)

it's telling the truth.  i can't find ActionLog / Get in the API Explorer.

Comment: Hi Mike, to report a bug, please check out issues.civicrm.org. Then you can return here and answer your own question with a link to the bug; free rep for you and an easy answer for future searches.

Comment: ok -- reported it (though i have to admit i WAG'd on some of those fields...

Comment: Just wondering if anybody who's experiencing this issue has CiviRules installed, I installed it 2 days ago and now I get the same error, never happened before.

Answer (score 2):

The JIRA issue appears to be [this one](https://issues.civicrm.org/jira/browse/CRM-17128)
It is marked as CLOSED and "cannot reproduce"

Comment: and i see Cullen has commented on there